# DARTS Time Series Ensemble Regression Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, ensemble-learning, u8darts

I am trying to implement an ensemble of 4 DARTS models each having fit and predict methods. My goal is as follows :

- I have a dataframe with 10 columns (including the target column that I want to forecast ahead)
- The rest of the 9 columns are covariate columns helping in the forecasting of the target column.
- The whole training dataset has 40 monthly frequency rows ending at say 22nd Oct 2022. I want to forecast the target for next month i.e. Nov 2022.

These models **individually** work smoothly on the dataset, but together in this ensemble they seem to throw an error. I have a created a small minimalistic reproducible code below, very similar to mine, which throws the same error.

```
col1 = list(np.arange(1,40))
col2 = list(np.arange(41,80))
col3 = list(np.arange(81,120))
col4 = list(np.arange(121,160))

month = pd.date_range('2019-08-01','2022-10-01',freq='1MS').strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()

dt = {'col1': col1,'col2':col2,'col3':col3,'target':col4,'month':month}
df = pd.DataFrame(dt)
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['month'])
df.index = df['month']
df = df.drop(['month'],axis = 1)


X_train_t = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df,value_cols=list(df.columns.drop(["col3"])),freq="1MS")
y_train_t = TimeSeries.from_dataframe(df,freq = '1MS',value_cols = 'target')

#Initializing model and fitting
torch_metrics = SymmetricMeanAbsolutePercentageError()
model1 = XGBModel(lags= [-1,-2,-3], lags_past_covariates=[-1,-2,-3],random_state = 42,output_chunk_length=1)
model2 = LightGBMModel(lags= [-1,-2,-3], lags_past_covariates=[-1,-2,-3],random_state = 42,output_chunk_length=1)
model3 = CatBoostModel(lags= [-1,-2,-3], lags_past_covariates=[-1,-2,-3], lags_future_covariates=None, output_chunk_length=1,random_state = 42)
model4 = BlockRNNModel(input_chunk_length=12,model = 'GRU',dropout=0.2,random_state = 42,output_chunk_length = 1)
forecasting_models = [model1,model2,model3,model4]

regression_model  =RandomForest(lags=None, lags_past_covariates=None, lags_future_covariates=[0], output_chunk_length=1, add_encoders=None, n_estimators=100, max_depth=None)
model_ensemble = RegressionEnsembleModel(forecasting_models = forecasting_models, regression_train_n_points =38,regression_model = regression_model)
history = model_ensemble.fit(y_train_t,past_covariates = X_train_t)

pred = model_ensemble.predict(n=1, series = y_train_t,past_covariates = X_train_t)
```

Following is the whole error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/3395707719.py in <module>
     12 regression_model  =RandomForest(lags=None, lags_past_covariates=None, lags_future_covariates=[0], output_chunk_length=1, add_encoders=None, n_estimators=100, max_depth=None)
     13 model_ensemble = RegressionEnsembleModel(forecasting_models = forecasting_models, regression_train_n_points =38,regression_model = regression_model)
---> 14 history = model_ensemble.fit(y_train_t,past_covariates = X_train_t)
     15 
     16 pred = model_ensemble.predict(n=1, series = y_train_t,past_covariates = X_train_t)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/regression_ensemble_model.py in fit(self, series, past_covariates, future_covariates)
    119                 series=forecast_training,
    120                 past_covariates=past_covariates,
--> 121                 future_covariates=future_covariates,
    122             )
    123 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/forecasting_model.py in _fit_wrapper(self, series, past_covariates, future_covariates)
   1820             future_covariates=future_covariates
   1821             if self.supports_future_covariates
-> 1822             else None,
   1823         )
   1824 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/xgboost.py in fit(self, series, past_covariates, future_covariates, val_series, val_past_covariates, val_future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts, **kwargs)
    219             future_covariates=future_covariates,
    220             max_samples_per_ts=max_samples_per_ts,
--> 221             **kwargs,
    222         )
    223 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/regression_model.py in fit(self, series, past_covariates, future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts, n_jobs_multioutput_wrapper, **kwargs)
    481 
    482         self._fit_model(
--> 483             series, past_covariates, future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts, **kwargs
    484         )
    485 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/regression_model.py in _fit_model(self, target_series, past_covariates, future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts, **kwargs)
    363 
    364         training_samples, training_labels = self._create_lagged_data(
--> 365             target_series, past_covariates, future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts
    366         )
    367 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/models/forecasting/regression_model.py in _create_lagged_data(self, target_series, past_covariates, future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts)
    334             lags_future_covariates=lags_future_covariates,
    335             max_samples_per_ts=max_samples_per_ts,
--> 336             multi_models=self.multi_models,
    337         )
    338 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/utils/data/tabularization.py in _create_lagged_data(target_series, output_chunk_length, past_covariates, future_covariates, lags, lags_past_covariates, lags_future_covariates, max_samples_per_ts, is_training, multi_models)
    150             "Unable to build any training samples of the target series "
    151             + (f"at index {idx} " if len(target_series) > 1 else "")
--> 152             + "and the corresponding covariate series; "
    153             "There is no time step for which all required lags are available and are not NaN values.",
    154         )

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/logging.py in raise_if(condition, message, logger)
    102         if `condition` is satisfied
    103     """
--> 104     raise_if_not(not condition, message, logger)
    105 
    106 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/darts/logging.py in raise_if_not(condition, message, logger)
     76     if not condition:
     77         logger.error("ValueError: " + message)
---> 78         raise ValueError(message)
     79 
     80 

ValueError: Unable to build any training samples of the target series and the corresponding covariate series; There is no time step for which all required lags are available and are not NaN values.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in the following line:

```
model_ensemble = RegressionEnsembleModel(forecasting_models=forecasting_models, regression_train_n_points=38, regression_model=regression_model)
```

By giving the value `38` on a dataset of 39 points leaves a single point for the training of your list of time-series models, which cannot produce the lag values (-1 , -2, -3).

Maybe you misinterpreted the meaning of the `regression_train_n_points` parameter: it is the number of point used by the regression *ensambling* RandomForest model, and not by the list of time-series regressors.

Comment: Hi @spallas. I still dont understand regression_train_n_points. Does the whole dataset get divided between the Ensembling Random Forest model and the list of time-series model? If so why? I mean shouldn't the whole thing use the same set of data to figure out which weighted output combination of the predictions gives the best result? So lets say for instance I have 41 rows of data for each column (including target). I want the ensemble to learn the best way to regress this combination of models, how many points should I give for regression_train_n_points and GRU input chunk length separately?

Comment: Because I think only GRU needs to know the length of the input chunk length. So the list of models should have at least input_chunk_length (GRU) + output_chunk_length(GRU)?

Comment: Yes the dataset is split between the two. The reason is that the Ensembling Random Forest needs to learn which set of models is best on unseen data (not seen by the list of models) the regression_train_n_points sets the dimension of this unseen dataset. Without two datasets the ensembler would always choose the model with lowest error on the train set. 
So you need two separate datasets.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking for an answer for a little over a month now! I changed the regression_train_n_points and GRU input/output length to match the total rows. It processes properly now!